# Is Java's applet the only way for the Java SE to work on a website?

Tags: java, applet, standards

Does Java SE (Standard Edition) offer a way to make its programs work online beside the Applets? Or is the applet the only way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [Webstart](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp) to allow users to launch your Java application from a website and have the application communicate back with a server.  As with applets, Webstart applications run in a sandbox by default and hence you should look into signing your application jar to allow it to communicate over the network.

You could also consider GWT or Servlets / JSP if your aim is to write a web application rather than deploy a standalone app.  It all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Java is trying to make a comeback on the client-side with a new technology called [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/).

Not sure if that is not just an applet under the hood, though.

And then there is [WebStart](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp), which launches Java applications from a website (although they then run outside of the browser).

Comment: The general response to JavaFX seems to be deafening in its silence.

Comment: AFAIK JavaFX can be used in all the different Java GUI contexts, including Applets and WebStart. It is in some ways a replacement for Swing, although for more complex things you might still need to mix in some Swing. It all compiles down to Java bytecode.

Comment: I heard about JavaFX, but I really hava no idea where does it fit in the Java world.

Comment: Back in 2008 they showed alot of it at the Java One conference, it provides support for alot of multimedia, video/audio playback/recording, it mostly reminded me of flash in the visual sense, being used to build a pretty application.

Answer (score 2):

The only I know of are Java Applet and JavaFX

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.